# The equivalent of this loop in Jinja

Tags: loops, python-2.7, flask, jinja2

I would like to know how can I perform this loop in Jinja :

```
for r,s in (v,t):
    #Do something
```

When I try to write something similar in Jinja(Flask), I had an error :

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

`v` and `t` are lists of dicts .

Comment: to perform this you will need to use `zip` :   check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17520816/2692771

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found : In jinja I should use `zipped`

```
{% for s, t in zipped %}
#do something
{% endfor %}
```

where `zipped = zip (s,t)`